# How to prevent switching Print key shortcut back?

Tags: shortcut-keys, settings, system-settings, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I've set my Print key to Take a screenshot of an area, but every time I logout and login it changes back to Take a screenshot (of full screen) without unsettin the old one ?! and saves the full screen until I change it back. How can I prevent this?!

**Edit:** sorry, my first explanation was badly understandable, I will try once more:
I assign the <kbd>Print</kbd> to the area screenshot. In that case, it prompts window saying that it is already assigned to fullscreen screenshot, I say OK.
Then, I logout and login and <kbd>Print</kbd> is assigned automatically to fullscreen screenshot and without overwriting the area screenshot

[image: the keyboard shortcuts window (sorry for czech interface)]

Answer (score 1):

The situation where both shortcuts use the same key should not happen, when I tried your settings, I've been prompted to confirm that the Fullscreen screenshot will be disabled.

So I got this:

[image]

To store such configuration in the dconf database you can use the command line. Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot 'Print'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot ''
```

You could even assign the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> to the fullscreen screenshot:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot '<Shift>Print'
```

Now you can logout and login and keep your desired configuration.

Comment: The commands behavior is same as in GUI :(
I have better explained the problem in heading.

Comment: I tested those commands (and the GUI) with 13.10 and they worked (changes persisted after logout/login), are you using 14.04? Did you install some applications that could interfere with the shortcuts?

Comment: I'm using 14.04, but if I good remember this bug was happening in 13.10 too.